# div's position changes after adding php file

Tags: php, web

I have a php code like this which mainly fetch rss feed from a site

```
<?php
     $xmlstr = file_get_contents("http://news.myweb.com.au/index.php?format=feed&amp;type=rss");    
     $xml_object = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);    
     $items = $xml_object->channel->item;
?>    
<?php foreach($items as $item):?>    
    <h1> <?php echo $item->title;?> </h1>       
    <p >
        <?php echo substr($item->description, 0, 250);?>...
        <a href="<?php echo $item->link;?>">Read More</a>
    </p>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
now I am including that file in some other file like this

<div class="leftColumnH">               
    <?php include('blog.php');?>
</div>

<div class="rightColumnH">                              
<h2  class="fontstyle leftColumnText ">Web Development & Graphic Design</h2>
some test here                      
</div>
```

But while I see it in browser, "rightcolumn" goes inside a div with class "feed-description" inside leftColunm.

Comment: are you using float for leftColumnH and rightColumnH?? Can you post your CSS for those classes also?

Comment: there may be some undefined error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that your `<?php echo substr($item->description, 0, 250);?>` is not echoeing any div tag. If `$item->description` has `<div>` tag, then your truncate might be removing the `</div>` tag.
If its echoing div tag then close the tag.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks... correct code the working code is <?php echo substr($item->description, 0, 250);?>
<?php if(strlen($item->description)>244) echo "</div>";?>

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using float for leftColumnH and rightColumnH.

When you use float for child div, parent div's height will not be set to child div's height unless your parent div also have float attribute.

For example:

Create these classes

```
.parent{ border:1px solid red;}
.childLeft{border:1px solid blue;float:left;width:49%; height:100px;} 
.childRight{border:1px solid blue;float:right;width:49%; height:100px;}
```

Now in your html file

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="childLeft"></div>
  <div class="childRight"></div>
</div>
```

If you run this file you will be able to see your child divs will not be included inside your parent div properly.

To make that just try to apply float attribute to your parent div also. Refer below CSS

```
.parent{ border:1px solid red;float:left;width:100%}
```

Now if you run this file then you can see your child divs will be included in your parent div.

I refer you to check this one in your code and do the necessary style changes. This is nothing to do with PHP.  You better post your CSS code with your parent div and its CSS code also. Because I answer you, by assuming that you are using float for child divs.

Comment: It bahaved ok before I added the php part.yes leftColumnH and rightColumnH has float , they are both float to left and width is 50% of their parent and tey dont have any height.